# How can I handle exceptions in exactly the same way for a set of methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, metaprogramming

I'm building an api wrapper library. There are a set of methods are are simple "getters", that go into certain hashes and pull out strings.

For all of these, there might be a `nil` hash or some other data problem (not network problems, I'm handling those elsewhere). If such a problem is encountered, I want to raise a `DataError` exception and then handle those exceptions in the user interface. So I have a `handle_data_error` method which accepts a block, and if the block raises an error, I catch it and raise a `DataError`.

Is there any way to elegantly wrap the entire contents of a set of methods in this method, without having to type it in there 15 times? Any way to tell a class "handle these sorts of errors this way"? It occurs to me maybe I should look at the implementation of Rails' `rescue_from`.

Comment: What do you mean by nil hash? nil is not a hash. Do you mean **empty** hash?

Comment: something that could either be a hash, or nil :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rescue_from` only works in controllers.

When you have a lot of similar methods you can refactor them to either call a common core method where you handle errors:

```
class Foo
  def m1
    m 1
  end

  def m2
    m 2
  end

  def m(arg)
    begin
      # try
    rescue
      # handle error
    end
  end
end
```

or use `method_missing` to handle all of those method calls, and handle errors there:

```
class Foo
  def method_missing(method, *args, block)
    (super and return) unless method =~ /whatever/
    begin
      #try
    rescue
      # handle error
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: "rescue_from only works in controllers" -- yes but I think its metaprogramming is achieving the magic catch-all behavior i'm wanting for my class, so it's implementation is worth exploring :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the error in a central way, maybe your methods should not throw an error, instead catching errors and transport them e.g. to a

- central listener which takes the errors and dispatches them, or
- a handler which does something based on the error...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return `DataError` when `hash` lacks `key`, you can do:

```
hash.fetch(key, DataError.new)
```